# Mouseover popup (Mini page layout) on related list

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, related-list, popup

The mini page layout is a nice feature, but it is not consistent. Example: it seems to work for lookup fields on custom objects and when hovering over custom object records in the Recent Items (left bar on Home tab), but not when hovering over record ids in related lists. Why not?? Is there any way to make this work? Note that I am using junction object to link related records, and there is NO VISUALFORCE. Only standard page layouts for custom objects.

I have checked that the mini page layout contains the proper columns. I have also ticked the checkmark for "Related Lists" for "Notes and Attachments". However, when the mini page layout is displayed through the Recent Items left bar, the note/attachments are not displayed even if the record contains notes. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The checkmarks for “Related Lists” on the mini page layout only affects the display of a record in a Console view.

From the [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=console_definelayouts.htm&siteLang=en_US):

> Related lists on mini page layouts only display in the Console tab, not hover details.

For example, if you set the Top Sidebar Custom Console Component for the Case Layout to be a Lookup to the Account, you’ll see the related Account record in the top panel of the Console along with the related lists that you checked on the Account’s mini page layout set up.

Here's the result of a Case Console Component of the Account lookup in the Top Sidebar with the Account's mini page layout specifying that the Notes & Attachments related list should be displayed.

[image: Case in console with Account Mini Page]